# Gratitude for relief from pain

Tags: blessing

According to the [Orthodox Union website](http://ou.org.s3.amazonaws.com/publications/brachot/intro.htm) "No brachah is required either before or after taking medicine, even with water".

Hopefully, after taking painkillers such as paracetamol, the pain which drove one to take the medicine passes. How might one express one's gratitude at being relieved from pain?

Comment: The final line of one of the Morning Blessings seems appropriate? *Baruch atah Adonai, rofei chal basar umafliy la'asot* Blessed are you, Hashem, who heals all flesh and acts wondrously

Comment: why do you need an official blessing to thank God?

Comment: @ray who said I asked explicitly for an official blessing? If one exists I would like to know it; if one doesn't I shall quite happily find my own way of making sure I make the most of this opportunity for being grateful to him, but nonetheless would like to sure that I'm not, *en passant*, being inappropriate.

Comment: @monica cellio - this would be an example of what I mentioned

Comment: That last comment did not ping Monica Cellio. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time you use the washroom, there's the blessing afterwards *asher yatzar* thanking God for the intricate workings of the human body; try and have a little more concentration when saying that.

You could also try [Psalm 30](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2630.htm); "I called out to You G-d, and You healed me."

That's just a few suggestions on how to express gratitude.

The formal *bracha* set of *shehakol*, *hamotzee*, and afterwards *birkat hamazon*, *borei nefashot*, and the like are all derived from / patterned after the Torah verse that "after you eat and are satisfied, bless God" -- those were intended for ordinary foods that you eat out of hunger, not medicines. But thanking G-d in other ways for relief of pain is certainly appropriate.

Comment: just a side note re: Asher Yatzar http://www.torah.org/features/firstperson/everythingablessing.html

Comment: Thank you Shalom. The line I quoted in the comments is the last line of *asher yatzar* so I'm glad to see that my instincts were right there :) That line *"heals all flesh and acts wonderously"* really resonates for me - as does the whole blessing in fact: as an expression of gratitude that one always reminds me that no matter what we're suffering from, our bodies contain more things than we can imagine that we can be thankful for. Thank you also for the reminder of the line in Psalm 30. I've always taken that purely spiritually - it didn't occur to me to think of it in its literal sense too!

Comment: So shehakol is d'oraysa?...

Comment: @mevaqesh we assume the bracha as formulated is derabanan; at the simplest level, k'ein deorasya, on foodstuffs. I've modified language accordingly. However the Gemara also applies a svara from birkat hamazon -- if we thank when full, we must obviously thank while hungry. R' Yaakov Weinberg zt'l observed that a Gmara's svara is of deoraysa strength (e.g. mai chazis), so he suggested that *some* expression of gratitude beforehand is a deoraysa; the particular format is derabanan. Not unlike zachor es yom hashabbos vis-a-vis kiddush.